# How to disable the DEFLATE module for a specific directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

I am trying to figure out how to disable the DEFLATE module (gzipping) for a specific directory on my server. This is what I have in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

I can add something to my .htaccess file in the specific directory or even add a something to my /vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/conf/vhosts.conf file. I can't seem to get it to work though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed my original code from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and added this to my vhost.conf on this domain

```
<Directory "/var/www/rockchurch.com/httpdocs">
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

php_admin_value open_basedir none
php_admin_value safe_mode off
Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/rockchurch.com/httpdocs/tiny">
RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE html txt xml css js php
</Directory>
```

And works well. Apparently having it in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf universally adds it to all domains, which is great, but can't be changed in specific directories elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish this is to put the following line in a `.htaccess` file in the target directory:

```
 SetEnv no-gzip 1
```

It worked for me when the GZIP was causing issues with *mod_substitute*.